# vcard manager in android

Tags: android, android-sdk-1.6, android-contacts

I want to make VCard manager in android for 1.5 and above . This application will be able to perform following functions:
1 **Send and receive contact** . I want that when i send a contact to any mobile it should get the save option to save the contact and if some send me a business card then i should be able to save it in my contacts.

Can you please suggest me how to do it. 
Is there any particular format for sending a VCard . For eg in nokia phones we are able to send a contact and its details(email etc) in form of business card and the other person can save it .

Can the same thing be achieved in android ?

Regards
Gaurav Gupta

Comment: What are you talking about? What's a VCard?

Comment: @Falmarri http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard
For the format and stuff I would suggest normal *.vcf files. You can use the phone to react on special file formats and connect these to apps. If there would be a *vcf file, it would open your app and do some stuff with it. The vcf Format itself is text-based and should be easy to parse (per line and via regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ Keenora Fluffball

HI i am able to fetch the contacts details and able to send it in the format specified by you..  when i receive  vcard in that format i want that i should get a **save to contacts option.** Though i can do this by using broad cast receiver. if a message contains text like **BEGIN:VCARD**

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Gaurav;TEL;PREF9780898201
END:VCARD

But what about the other phones whether they will respond to it like in nokia  we get popup business card received.

I want it to work on all phones. whether it is nokia or android. 
Please suggest..

Comment: have you find the solution?